# Efficient Empirical CDF Computation / Storage

Tags: python, optimization, statistics, bioinformatics

I'm trying to precompute the distributions of several random variables. In particular, these random variables are the results of functions evaluated at locations in a genome, so there will be on the order of 10^8 or 10^9 values for each. The functions are pretty smooth, so I don't think I'll lose much accuracy by only evaluating at every 2nd/10th/100th? base or so, but regardless there will be a large number of samples. My plan is to precompute quantile tables (maybe percentiles) for each function and reference these in the execution of my main program to avoid having to compute these distribution statistics in every run.

But I don't really see how I can easily do this: storing, sorting, and reducing an array of 10^9 floats isn't really feasible, but I can't think of another way that doesn't lose information about the distribution. Is there a way of measuring the quantiles of a sample distribution that doesn't require storing the whole thing in memory?

Comment: I think you might have more luck on http://stats.stackexchange.com/...

Comment: How many variables? How "smooth" are the functions? Can you use local polynomials for interpolation?

Comment: The functions represent different measures of proximity to various types of genes. I want to try out different metrics, but they all can be boiled down to "(some kind of) distance to the nearest gene of type X". So the values would probably look something like: http://i.imgur.com/hVyIO.png repeated over and over again (with different heights and lengths), and a histogram could have pretty much any shape, depending on how far apart the relevant genes are. Is that slightly clearer? Using the CDF, I could compute a score for a position and the probability of getting this high a score by chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @katriealex's comment: ask someone w/ a strong statistics background.

You could easily evaluate min/max/mean/std deviation w/o needing to store any significant amount of memory. (note for mean + std deviation: use Knuth's technique:

```
delta = x - m[n-1]
m[n] = m[n-1] +  1/n * delta
S[n] = S[n-1] + (x[n] - m[n])*delta
mean = m[n]
std dev = sqrt(S[n]/n)
```

This prevents you from floating point overflow/underflow problems encountered in the naive calculation of std dev, e.g. [taking S1 = the sum of x[k] and S2 = the sum of x[k]^2 and trying to calculate std deviation = sqrt(S2/N - S1^2/N^2)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Na.C3.AFve_algorithm). See also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Rapid_calculation_methods).)

There are probably other stream-oriented algorithms for computing higher characteristic moments of the distribution, but I don't know what they are.

Or alternatively, you could also use [histogramming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) techniques with enough bins to characterize the distribution.

Comment: Mean and standard deviation aren't quite sufficient for this, but I think that binning will actually work out just fine, especially since I'm free to normalize my scoring function so that I know the upper and lower limits. Thanks for the suggestion.